# How can I specify a CategoryAttribute on a DynamicProperty created with LINQ dynamic expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, propertygrid

Thank you for taking the time to look at this question.

I have the following code:

```
    public partial class TemplateEditor : Form {
    private object dynamicObject;
    private Type dynamicType;
    private Dictionary<string, string> properties;
    public TemplateEditor() {
        InitializeComponent();
        properties = new Dictionary<string, string> {{ "Name 1", "Value 1" },
                                                     { "Name 2", "2nd Thing" },
                                                     { "Name 3", "Third" }};
        var dynamicProperties = new List<DynamicProperty>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in properties) {
            dynamicProperties.Add(new DynamicProperty(pair.Key, typeof(string)));
        }
        dynamicType = DynamicExpression.CreateClass(dynamicProperties);
        dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicType);
        propertyGrid.SelectedObject = dynamicObject;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in properties) {
            dynamicType.GetProperty(pair.Key).SetValue(propertyGrid.SelectedObject, pair.Value, null);
        }
    }
    private void CopyDynamicObjectValuesToDictionary() {
        var updatedTemplateProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in properties) {
            string value = (string)dynamicType.GetProperty(pair.Key).GetValue(propertyGrid.SelectedObject, null);
            updatedTemplateProperties.Add(pair.Key, value);
        }
        properties = updatedTemplateProperties;
        // Display Updated Dictionary
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in properties) {
            textBox1.AppendText(pair.Key);
            textBox1.AppendText(": \"");
            textBox1.AppendText(pair.Value);
            textBox1.AppendText("\" of type ");
            textBox1.AppendText(typeof(string).ToString());
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    private void OnShowValuesButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CopyDynamicObjectValuesToDictionary();
    }
}
```

Which I am using to display an editable Dictionary in a PropertyGrid.  It is based on this article: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2009/03/02/reduce-propertygrid-development-pain-by-using-linq-dynamic-expressions.aspx

I like this technique because it is a pretty simple way to get dynamic data into a PropertyGrid.

My question is: "How can I set the CategoryAttribute for each DynamicProperty so that they can be grouped in the PropertyGrid?"

I intend to have a third list which contains the Category information for each item in the Dictionary.

After Googling for hours it seems one is only supposed to do this at compile time for classes created at design time.  However I suspect there must be a way to do it for dynamically created objects/properties.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like this might be as close as I come to figuring it out.  Answering my own question for reference.

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1016749/Re-nice.aspx